# dependency error while installing openssh client

Tags: openssh

As you can see from the image I am unable to install `openssh-client` because of dependency error, I have tried this process on a different machine and it worked but it doesn't work on my machine can anyone tell me why?
[image]

Comment: Any reasons to install the openssh-client with a deb package? Run `sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get install openssh-client`

Comment: no particular reason, just wanted to why it works on one machine and why it doesn't work on another.

Comment: Use the same repositories as in the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

Running `apt-get install openssh-clients` is preferred way as already mentioned, but I just wanted to answer your questions:

From repository using `apt-get` you will get not only the actual package (`deb`), but also dependencies (dependent packages). This can't happen when installing using `dpkg`, because `dpkg` does not have any information about your repositories and just install what gets as a file. The dependent packages are in different `deb` files you would have to provide separately.

> works on one machine and why it doesn't work on another.

The reason why it does work for you on different machine is probably simple that you have `libssl` already installed on the one machine, but not on the other.

Comment: thnx for your response,it really helped!